# Tamil characters show as garbage in shell buffer but ok in files

Tags: character-encoding, utf-8

When printing non-latin characters like the ones from my mother tongue Tamil in shell, it appears weird(left side window in the image). When I open the file with Tamil characters they are rendered correctly(right side window in the image). I have set the shell locale to utf-8 but the problem still persists.

[image: screenshot]

```
vanangamudi@kaikuttai:~/home/projects/code/oneoff-experiments/tamil-etymdict-visualizer$ python3 -i generate-dot.py
100% 53753/53753 [00:00<00:00, 163166.71it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate-dot.py", line 32, in <module>
    write_dot(G, 'graph.dot')         
  File "/home/vanangamudi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_agraph.py", line 192, in write_dot
    A = to_agraph(G)
  File "/home/vanangamudi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/drawing/nx_agraph.py", line 151, in to_agraph
    A.add_node(n)
  File "/home/vanangamudi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 309, in add_node
    node = Node(self, nh=nh)
  File "/home/vanangamudi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygraphviz/agraph.py", line 1611, in __new__
    n = super(Node, self).__new__(self, gv.agnameof(nh), graph.encoding)
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found
>>> G.nodes
NodeView(('à®¨à¯à®°à¯à®à¯à®à¯à®´à®¿|à®¨à¯à®°à¯à®à¯à®à¯à®´à®¿|à®ªà¯', '(n', 'à®¨à¯à®°à¯', 'à®ªà¯à®´à¯', 'à®¤à¯à®³à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à®²à¯', 'à®à¯à®±à¯à®¤à®²à¯', 'fowl', 'à®à¯à®´à®¿', 'à®µà®©à¯à®©à®¤à¯à®²à®¿à®à¯|à®µà®©à¯à®©à®¤à¯à®²à®¿à®à¯|à®ªà¯', '|à®ªà¯', 'à®à®³à®µà®¾à®à®®à¯|à®à®³à®µà®¾à®à®®à¯|à®ªà¯', 'à®à¯', 'à®à¯', 'à®µà®¿', 'à®à¯à®à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à¯à®£à®¿|à®à¯à®à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à¯à®£à®¿|à®ªà¯', 'à®à¯à®©à¯à®±à®¾à®µà®¿', 'à®à®²à¯à®à¯|à®à®²à¯à®à¯
```

Adding locale information as pointed out by @Rusi,

```
vanangamudi@kaikuttai:~$ locale
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
vanangamudi@kaikuttai:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
ta_IN
ta_IN.utf8
ta_LK
ta_LK.utf8
vanangamudi@kaikuttai:~$
```

Comment: Is your font able to display those characters outside Emacs?

Comment: No. Looks at the code segment above. I just copy pasted the emacs text and it appears as circle around R plus something. I am able to type and print tamil text inside emacs as seen in the right side of the window. and the output from networkx written to file and rendered using graphviz display correct characters.

Comment: Pls run (1) locale and (2) locale -a. Do this from a shell (outside emacs) and update ur q with the results.

Comment: LANG is *not* utf-8. Why?? Also the mismatch between Lang and other LC variables. Of course with LC_ALL set it should not matter. Contents of /etc/default/locale should set LANG to en_US.utf8 and nothing else should be set there. Can u check? Also can u try (at shell) : LANG=en_US.utf8 emacs -q"?

Comment: Also the LANGUAGE is unnecessarily inconsistent. Try removing. (can put back if needed)

Comment: See my addition at bottom of my answer and please add to your question

Answer (score 1):

## Diagnosis

Clearly at this point we have only insufficient data. Anyways... here's  my tentative diagnosis

- `LANG` is set `en_IN` (no utf8) in `/etc/default/locale`; `LANGUAGE` too is set there to `en_IN:en`
- `LC_ALL` is set *somewhere else* to `en_US.utf8`
- In short, your system is in a tug-o-war between IN-dia and US-a, between utf8 and legacy encoding and emacs is getting confused.

## Suggested Treatment

Assuming the above somewhat true, you need to

- Add the utf8 to `LANG` setting
- Find and remove wherever `LC_ALL` is being set
- verify working by calling `locale`. All should be same. `LC_ALL` **should show as unset**
- Try emacs without any attempted locale related customizations. I would guess that shell-inside-emacs has more things that could go wrong than simply reading/writing Tamil files. And python-unicode even more so. So for testing purposes I'd start with the reading/writing Tamil files. For python-unicode, first try in a shell outside emacs.

## Finding LANG/LC_* settings

This can be a non-trivial treasure hunt.
Some likely culprits

- /etc/default/locale (debian/ubuntu)
- /etc/environment (older debian/ubuntu)
- /etc/profile
- In your $HOME

  - .pam_environment
  - .profile
  - .bash_profile
  - .bashrc
- etc...

Unfortunately this list cannot be exhaustive And at this point is getting quite far removed from emacs.

---

Also please report

```
 M-: (process-coding-system (get-process "???"))
```

where ??? Is `shell` or `Shell` or `*shell*` ... I'm not exactly sure which will work

And, if necessary, use `set-process-coding-system`. ( [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Information.html#Process-Information) )