# Setting latex compiler

Tags: latex, init-file, config, configuration-files

I was happily running emacs with a locally installed texlive in ~/texlive/2021 on manjaro KDE. But I decided to switch to Gnome. So, installed necessary packages, removed the ones I did not need and am now using Gnome without any problem.

When I opened emacs to compile a tex file (something I have been doing for a very long time), it suddenly produced an error:

```
Suspicious state from syntax checker tex-chktex: Flycheck checker tex-chktex returned 1, but its output contained no errors: warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /usr/bin:/usr/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/bin/texmf/web2c:/usr:/usr/share/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/texmf-local/web2c:/usr/texmf-dist/web2c:/usr/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c:/://share/texmf-local/web2c://share/texmf-dist/web2c://share/texmf/web2c://texmf-local/web2c://texmf-dist/web2c://texmf/web2c.
chktex: WARNING -- Could not find global resource file.
chktex: ERROR -- Illegal verbosity level.

Try installing a more recent version of tex-chktex, and please open a bug report if the issue persists in the latest release.  Thanks!
```

In my zsh shell, Output of `whereis xelatex` shows:

```
xelatex: /usr/bin/xelatex /home/sandip/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex
```

`echo $PATH` shows:

```
/home/sandip/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/sandip/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/
```

In a terminal, if I run `~/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex test.tex` it compiles without error. But if I run `xelatex test.tex`, it produces an error.

So, I thought that the error is happening because emacs is looking at the files in /usr/bin whereas it should be looking at files in ~/texlive/2021/bin.

So, I tried the solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37291/auctex-does-not-recognize-texlive-installation). Now `M-x getenv PATH` shows:

```
/home/user/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/sandip/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/sandip/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/
```

But the problem persists.

How do I tell emacs to look at the correct place?

Comment: Make sure that your texlive installation directory comes first, both in `PATH` (presumably set in some shell initialization file) and also in `exec-path` which is what emacs uses to find executables. I'm pretty sure that at initialization, `exec-path` is set from `PATH`, but if you change the latter later, the change does not automatically propagate to `exec-path`.

Comment: To add to what @nickd said: if you are starting emacs in a gui-ish way (eg startup apps) you may get mismatches between PATH and exec-path which may disappear when you start it from the shell. (just a debugging suggestion)

Comment: @NickD Thanks. I updated my .zshrc to prepend my texlive installation. Now, `echo $PATH` in my terminal shows `/home/sandip/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/:/home/sandip/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl`. Even a simple `xelatex test.tex` works without error in the terminal. `which xelatex` shows texlive installation. `M-x getenv` shows texlive installation at the very beginning and still the problem persists!

Comment: Does `exec-path` agree with `PATH`?

Comment: @NickD Thanks. That was the problem. I added `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/home/sandip/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:"
                         (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/home/sandip/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux")` to my `~/.doom.d/config.el` and things work as expected.

Comment: @NickD Please add this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'll try but it's a tricky question to answer fully and completely. I have the beginnings of an answer below, but it still needs a fair amount of work before it is a satisfactory answer.

Comment: With respect @nickd this setenv solution is a duct tape one : PATH is **wrong** and being **patched** not corrected. As it was 4 years ago for same OP!! https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37291/auctex-does-not-recognize-texlive-installation

Comment: I agree. The problem is how to describe the real solution: making sure that the emacs you get from the GUI has the same PATH definition (actually the same environment) as the one you get from the shell, so you can depend on it without having to patch it. The trouble is that that process (AFAIK) is not well-defined: it depends on how the GUI sets things up and that varies with the GUI. So the answer lays out some principles but does not describe exactly what you need to do to get there. The OP has chosen a way that works for him, but it is certainly not ideal: a duct-tape solution as you say.

Comment: @Nickd This [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56044/5223) has a list of files for shell settings (different q, similar issue). Can be expanded I guess

Comment: There are many questions (on SE, particularly on SuperUser SE and Ubuntu SE) that discuss this. Here is [one](https://superuser.com/questions/19044/how-do-i-set-an-environmental-variable-for-a-gnome-session) that captures some of the scale of the problem I think. Note the answer that says: "if you are in Gnome, do this; in KDE do that; in Wayland it's different ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your texlive installation directory comes first, both in `PATH` (presumably set in some shell initialization file) and also in `exec-path` which is what `emacs` uses to find executables. I'm pretty sure that at initialization, `exec-path` is set from `PATH`, but if you change the latter later, the change does not automatically propagate to `exec-path`. So you have to make sure that any changes to `PATH` are faithfully reflected in `exec-path` - otherwise, you will get different versions of the program when you run it from a shell than when it gets executed in `emacs`, perhaps by AucTeX or something similar.

It is also true as @Rusi points out in a comment, that when you start emacs from a shell command line, you might get a different value of `PATH` than if you start it by clicking on a button in the DE. That's because `PATH` is passed from the parent process to the child process in the environment, so `emacs` might end up with different values of `PATH` when it is started from a shell than when it is started from the GUI.

The problem with the OP's (duct-tape as @Rusi called it) solution is that there are now *two* places where `PATH` needs to be set: once in the shell initialization file, so that the shell will pick up the right executable and once in the `emacs` initialization file so that `emacs` will do so. That's a recipe for future problems. It would be better to have a single place where `PATH` is defined, so that both the shell's environment *and* the GUI environment would be able to get it, so that when emacs is started (either way) from them, it would inherit the correct value of `PATH` without having to worry about it itself (N.B BTW that doing the `setenv` in the emacs init file is "wrong": when emacs is started from the shell, then the additional directory would be added to `PATH` twice: once when the shell is initialized and then once more when `emacs` is initialized. That should not cause problems in finding the correct executable but it is probably less efficient).

Comment: @Rusi: I added a paragraph describing the problem that I see. That should go some way towards helping the OP understand what the problem is. Let me know what you think so far (but note that the answer is not finished: I'll add some more material in the weeks to come but I'm not sure it will ever be complete. BTW, feel free to edit (or suggest edits).

Comment: Better now -- thanks!